# Ninject ActivationException on ChildKernel

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm getting an ActivationException saying there was an error activating IEventBroker.  MyDataSource takes an IEventBroker has a parameter.  If I don't use the child kernel, there is no issue.  What is going on?

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var childKernel = new ChildKernel(kernel);
        var eventBroker = new EventBroker();
        childKernel.Bind<IEventBroker>().ToConstant(eventBroker);         
        var myDS = childKernel.Get<MyDataSource>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ChildKernel readme](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel):

> The default behavior of Ninject that classes are bound to themself if
>   not explicit still   exists. But in this case this will be done by the
>   top most parent. This means that   this class can not have any
>   dependency defined on a child kernel. I strongly suggest to   have a
>   binding for all objects that are resolved by ninject and not to use
>   this default behavior.

So you need to explicitly bind `MyDataSource` to self to make it work:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var childKernel = new ChildKernel(kernel);
var eventBroker = new EventBroker();
childKernel.Bind<IEventBroker>().ToConstant(eventBroker);
childKernel.Bind<MyDataSource>().ToSelf();
var myDS = childKernel.Get<MyDataSource>();
```